# Pythontex don't work ? why?

Tags: pythontex

I'm working with Windows 8, TeX Live 2015, and Python 3.4. I'm a newbie in LaTeX!

The installation of `pythontex` seems to be ok. I verify if all the files are at the right place. I try to make `pythontex` work with this code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
\begin{pycode} 
 print ("Hello \Latex ")
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

When I run in `cmd`:

- `pdflatex test.tex` → ok
- `pythontex.py test.py` → the file command doesn't exit

Do you have any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: ...that should probably be `\LaTeX`, not `\Latex`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i think i's a more complex solution because when i chnage it i've got :c:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript.tlu :680 :c:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript
.tlu:650 : program not found (not part of Tex LIve) :python.exe

Comment: You need to have a working version of Python, which is not provided by `pythontex`. See https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: thanks for the answer i already have python v 3.4 on my computer and it seems to work ?

Comment: Verify your paths are correct by running from the command line a known working *.py program saved in the same folder as that *.tex.

Comment: ok thanks i 've got a message error with the svrapi.dll

Comment: i reinstall the python v 3 for correcting this issue

Answer (score 6):

In addition to needing to correct the `\LaTeX` issue, you have a space before the print command.  Python will treat this as an improper indentation. Take the space out.  I ran the following code from inside TeXStudio, using a User command of `pythontex %.tex` in the user0 spot (ALT+SHIFT+F1).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}
    \LaTeX

\begin{pycode} 
print ('Hello, \LaTeX')
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

Don't forget to run `pdflatex` again after running `pythontex`.

Also, you must run `pythontex test.tex` not `test.py`.

The section of pythontex code that is throwing the latest error is in `pythontex3.py` in the `...your TeX distribution folder/scripts/pythontex` folder. It says:

```
# Check for compatility between the .pytxcode and the script
if 'version' not in settings or settings['version'] != data['version']:
    print('* PythonTeX error')
    print('    The version of the PythonTeX scripts does not match the last code')
    print('    saved by the document--run LaTeX to create an updated version.\n')
    sys.exit(1)
```

So it looks like there is an old version setting hanging around somewhere.  I'm not intimately familiar with all the settings and locations. Geoff Poore (the author) is a colleague, but he's not in the office right now. I'm sorry I can't give you more assistance immediately.

Comment: i have corrected the issue \LaTeX and the space it seems that i progress now i have the error This is PythonTex 0.14
*PythonTex error
the version of the PythonTexscripts does not match the last code
saved by the document

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get a notification that there was a comment.  See my addition on the last line of my answer.  I also suggest that you start with a clean setup.  If your TeX file is named `test.tex`, delete every `test.*` file in the folder except `test.tex` Also delete the folder `pythontex-files-test`. Then run your `pdflatex test.tex`, `pythontex test.tex`, `pdflatex test.tex`sequence and see if that works.

Comment: No problem bill thanks for your answer i don't find the folder python-files-test where it is ? but i try to clean up everything else but allways have the same error message  with the three compilation sequence ...at 2nd  compilation .... i also try with a new file test1 with the same content it didn't work ... some ideas ?

Comment: That's odd. If pythontex worked properly then it would create a subfolder in the folder where your tex file is.  Note that it would be `pythontex-files-test`, not `python-files-test`.  As far as the error you're seeing, I can't reproduce it so it must have something to do with your installation, either Python or the pythontex package. I would suggest downloading pythontex again and rehashing your TeX installation. Maybe @G.Poore can jump in here with an idea.

Comment: well with erase all the files of the installation and another installation rehashing texlive the problem is the same what's wrong with that ?

Comment: the complete error mesage is :This is PythonTex 0.14
PythonTex error
the version of the PythonTex scripts does not lmatch the laste code
saved by the document--run LaTeX to create an updated version.
c:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:659 command failed with exit code 1:python.exe 
c:/users/frederic/texmf/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py test1   any idea

Comment: See my edited answer above. Wish I could help more quickly.

Comment: i have test in another computer it works ! any idea how can i remove pythontex and reinstall it after @G.Poore

Comment: @fred62 It looks like you may have two installations of `pythontex` with different versions. You might search under `c:/users/frederic/texmf` and remove all folders called `pythontex`. Then you could use the TeX Live package manager to uninstall, and then reinstall, its version of `pythontex`. I would expect that to work, but that assumes you have sufficient admin privileges. If not, you might need to install everything under `c:/users/frederic/texmf`, and then make sure that it is that version of `pythontex` that is called when you run the `pythontex` command.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the following lines in `.tex` file:

```latex
\usepackage{pythontex}

\printpythontex

....

\begin{pycode}

print("Arbitrary text or results from the python code")

\end{pycode}

....
```

This is what you need at minimum in the `tex` code. 
Then:

1. Compile LaTeX file, for example `demo.tex`, in TeXstudio <kbd>F6</kbd>
2. Compile Python code. Easiest, open command window and run: `pythontex demo.tex`
3. Compile LaTeX file again in TeXstudio <kbd>F6</kbd>.

It should work.
If you have problems in you Python code, Python compilation will tell you what needs to be corrected.