# Pythontex error not compiling python

Tags: python, pythontex

I have a full installation of Texlive 2019 and both 2.7 and 3.7 versions of Python installed. I want to compile the following simple project wich contains a python command inside `pythontex` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\begin{pycode} 
print ('Hello, World')
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

I first compile with pdflatex and when I run `pythontex test.tex` python command the error I get is

```
C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:931:
C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:898: 
program not found (not part of TeX Live): python.exe
```

but I don't know if TexLive or Python installation is responsible for this. I tried to update Texlive but the problem remains. I also followed instuctions from this topic: [Pythontex doesn't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256203/pythontex-dont-work-why)

Comment: Pythontex cannot fined python; that's what the error message says. Can you run python on the commandline? Is it in the search path? See also https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/123

Comment: There are troubles with having two versions of python and using pythonTeX. There might be some advice in documentation. But, from my experience, best results are when you have one version of Python in your PATH.

Comment: I can run Python on the command line without problems. But I just installed in another computer Python 3.7 on Program Files (x86) folder and not the default one which is AppData and by adding Python to the Path the problem is fixed. However I haven't tried it yet on my computer which has a different version of Python.

Comment: I tried the same thing but I can't get it to work. Python is already in search path but I get the same error.

Comment: The reason of the issue was multiple installations of Python. Now the problem is solved.