# Easy way to include multiple image files from file directory through Python code?

Tags: python, pythontex

I am trying to include an unknown amount of image files with unknown file names in a document. My code is inspired by a comment on this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53465/206040

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
    Pictures:
    \begin{pycode}
        import os
        directory = "".""
        extension = ".png"
        files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.lower().endswith(extension)]
        
        for file in files:
            print r"\begin{figure}[!ht]"
            print r"\centering"
            print r"\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=10cm]{%s}" % file
            print r"\caption{File %s}" % file
            print r"\label{Serie}"
            print r"\end{figure}"
        \end{pycode}
    
\end{document}
```

The code is working but the images are not included in my pdf. How do I solve this or is there a better / easier way to do this?

By the way: I've wanted to use the `pythontex` package as it does not require using the `--enable-write18` option? But I also don't know if there is an even better way.

Comment: Your code looks OK. Did you enable the `--shell-escape` [flag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88740/what-does-shell-escape-do)  during compilation? This flag has to be set as TeX  requires shell access in order to interact with Python. `--enable-write18` is just a similar thing.

Comment: Yes, I have tried `txs:///pdflatex`, `txs:///pdflatex --shell-escape`, and `txs:///pdflatex --enable-write18` in TexStudio as compilation commands. It runs fine, but the images are not included in my pdf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with. I have taken the liberty to introduce slight changes in your code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
 
    Pictures:
 
\begin{pycode}
import os
import textwrap

directory = '.'
extension = '.png'

files = [fn for fn in os.listdir(directory) if fn.lower().endswith(extension)]

figs = []      
for count, filename in enumerate(files, 1):
    fixedfn = filename.replace(r'_', r'\_')
    fig = fr'''
            \begin{{figure}}[!ht]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=4cm]{{{filename}}}
            \caption{{File {fixedfn}}}
            \label{{Serie{count}}}
            \end{{figure}}
            '''
    figs.append(textwrap.dedent(fig))
    
print(''.join(figs))
\end{pycode}
    
\end{document}
```

To use this code, install pygments using `pip install pygments` in your Python environment.

Compiling is done in the following order:

1. Compile LaTeX file (e.g. in TeXStudio)
2. Navigate in the directory of your LaTeX file using `cd` and use `pythontex documentname.tex` in the terminal where "documentname" is the name of the LaTeX file.
3. Compile LaTeX file (e.g. in TeXStudio) again, pictures should now be visible!

Alternatively you can just use the following command as your standard compiler in TeXStudio:

```
txs:///pdflatex | pythontex %.tex | txs:///pdflatex
```

When run on my machine, the Python code produces the following LaTeX source code:

```latex
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{1200px-LaTeX_project_logo_bird.svg.png}
\caption{File 1200px-LaTeX\_project\_logo\_bird.svg.png}
\label{Serie1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{campusVigo_vistas01.png}
\caption{File campusVigo\_vistas01.png}
\label{Serie2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{opengraph-icon-200x200.png}
\caption{File opengraph-icon-200x200.png}
\label{Serie3}
\end{figure}
```

which results in:

[image: pdf]

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! After some testing, I finally made it work using your code. I had to install ***pygments*** using `pip install pygments` in my Python environment. Also I had to compile in TeXStudio first, then navigate to the folder of the tex file in the terminal using the `cd` command (change directory) and then use the command `pythontex documentname.tex` in the terminal where "documentname" is the name of the tex file and then compile in TeXStudio again. Also see this answer (just ignore the `\printpythontex` command): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276840/206040

Comment: Also one can use `txs:///pdflatex | pythontex %.tex | txs:///pdflatex` as the standard compiler in TeXStudio.