# pythontex does not consider certain changes unless I delete its files folder?

Tags: python, pythontex

In the past, I have asked a question about including multiple images through Python in a tex document and I was given a solution which worked great ([Link to the old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576376/easy-way-to-include-multiple-image-files-from-file-directory-through-python-code)).

**My new problem:** Now I have noticed that adding new images after already having compiled the document in LaTeX results into new images not being considered through pythontex. The new images are only added after I delete the `pythontex-files-[documentname]` folder manually. I find this manual task a little bit annoying and I am looking for either a way to automate this without breaking my code or maybe finding another simpler solution. Maybe I am just doing something wrong?

**Example:** Let's say I have the following file structure:

```
├── Images
│   ├── Interesting image.jpg
│   └── Some image.jpg
├── pythontex-files-test
│   └── [Some files made by pythontex]
├── test.pdf
├── test.tex
└── [.aux, .log, .pytxcode, and .gz files]
```

Now I run my code which works fine to add those images:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

My images:

\begin{pycode}
import os
import textwrap

directory = 'Images'
extension = '.jpg'

files = [fn for fn in os.listdir(directory) if fn.lower().endswith(extension)]
files.sort()

figs = []
for filename in files:
    caption = filename.replace(r'_', r'\_')
    caption = caption.split('.')[0]
    directory_file = directory+'/'+filename
    fig = fr'''
    \begin{{figure}}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{{{directory_file}}}
    \caption{{{caption}}}
    \end{{figure}}
    '''
    figs.append(textwrap.dedent(fig))

print(''.join(figs))
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this and I am happy with it:

[image]

Afterwards I am adding a new image to the *Images*-folder called *new-image.jpg*.

```
Images
├── Interesting image.jpg
├── new-image.jpg
└── Some image.jpg
```

I would like to have the new image added automatically when compiling again. My code runs fine without any errors BUT the new image is not added unless I delete the `pythontex-files-[documentname]` folder. Only after the manual deletion of that folder, the new image is added.

- I would like to know the reason behind this - I could not find anything related to this in the documentation on CTAN.
- Is there maybe an easy method to delete the folder automatically before compiling without doing the compilation in a Python file using `os.system('pdflatex '+filename+'.tex')`? I have already tried the following but it did not work:

  ```
  \begin{pycode}   
   import os
   import textwrap

   pythontex_folder = 'pythontex-files-test'

   pythontex_files = [os.path.join(pth, f) for pth, dirs, files in os.walk(pythontex_folder) for f in files]

   for pth in pythontex_files:
       os.remove(pth)
   [...]
   \end{pycode}
  ```
- Is there maybe different way to achieve what I want (for example by slightly changing my existing code)?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't know the why, but as an easy workaround, I would suggest that the first thing that the phyton code does is to check if the folder exists and delete it. It should not be very difficult to do

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I have tried that but it did not seem to work. After I use `os.remove(pth)` for each file in the folder, no image shows up anymore in the pdf document. However, it only seems to work if I manually delete all the files inside that folder (without using `os.remove(pth)` and the other code above) or the folder itself which is not desired as already mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caching mechanism of `pythontex` can create some problems. I think a really simple workaround is to save your code in a separate Python file and call it from LaTeX. In order to do this, we use the `--shell-escape` option in the compiler. In TeXStudio, this can be done by setting `txs:///pdflatex --shell-escape` as the standard compiler. Instead of printing out the code for figures, you can save them to a file and `\input` from LaTeX. For example, this can be your Python file `figure.py`:

```python
import os
import textwrap

directory = 'Images'
extension = '.jpg'

files = [fn for fn in os.listdir(directory) if fn.lower().endswith(extension)]
files.sort()

figs = []
for filename in files:
    caption = filename.replace(r'_', r'\_')
    caption = caption.split('.')[0]
    directory_file = directory+'/'+filename
    fig = fr'''
    \begin{{figure}}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{{{directory_file}}}
    \caption{{{caption}}}
    \end{{figure}}
    '''
    figs.append(textwrap.dedent(fig))

# save figure content to figure.vrb
with open('figure.vrb', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join(figs))
```

Here is a minimum working example for your TeX file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% call python script, here I assume the binary name is python3
\sys_shell_now:n {python3~figure.py}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% input the generated figure file
\input{figure.vrb}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much! I did have to use the `--shell-escape` option though in my compiler. In TeXStudio this could be `txs:///pdflatex --shell-escape`. I will edit your answer and add that bit of information. Take the bounty!

Comment: I should have mentioned that...Since you were able to use `pythontex`, I just assumed `--shell-escape` has been enabled before.