# Forcing LaTeX to rerun the same code every time with pythontex

Tags: pythontex

I do not know how to import a function from another file using pycode.

I have a file named csv_code.py with the following code,

```python
import csv
def create_csv():

header = ['name', 'degree']
data = ['Mark', 6]

with open('degrees.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

and in the same directory, I have a .tex file containing this code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
from csv_code import *
create_csv()
\end{pycode}

\csvautotabular{countries.csv}

\end{document}
```

It works good, but once it has been compiled if the code in csv_code is changed (let's say that instead of Mark now we use the name John) when compiled again the document doesn't suffer any changes.

I assume LaTeX is just lazy and as it has run that code already it doesn't run it again. Is there a way of forcing LaTeX to run that code every time?

I have read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594834/pythontex-does-not-consider-certain-changes-unless-i-delete-its-files-folder) a solution using `--shell-escape`. But I don't know how to set this up in VSCode and I would like to find a way that doesn't involve playing with the settings to make it easier if I share my code.

Comment: Does it help if you declare your imported file as a dependency explicitly using the `pytex.add_dependencies()` function of PythonTeX? Like here https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/27#issuecomment-28412480

Comment: Not really, but thank you. This has been useful to solve a different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, adding `pytex.add_dependencies('csv_code.py')` works. I think it's not a problem of LaTeX but of PythonTeX. PythonTeX does not look for changes in `csv_code.py`. I guess PythonTeX generally does not look for changes in imports. Therefore, you have to tell it that the file is a dependency.

The workflow to demonstrate it is as follows:

0. Clean all auxiliary files that might still be there
1. Compile document the first time

```
pdflatex main
python3 $(which pythontex) main
pdflatex main
```

2. PDF contains *Mark*
3. Change *Mark* to *John* in `csv_code.py`
4. Compile document the second time

```
python3 $(which pythontex) main
pdflatex main
```

5. PDF contains *John*

Here are the files. (I changed them a little to make them compilable. I hope I didn't change anything fundamental to your problem):

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\pyc{pytex.add_dependencies('csv_code.py')}

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
from csv_code import *
create_csv()
\end{pycode}

\IfFileExists{degrees.csv}{\csvautotabular{degrees.csv}}{}

\end{document}
```

`csv_code.py`:

```python
import csv

def create_csv():
    header = ['name', 'degree']
    data = ['Mark', 6]

    with open('degrees.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: I wasn't following the steps appropriately, thank you for the detailed explanation!
I agree that it seems like the problem is coming from PythonTeX, not LaTeX as I suggested.